# Get date from DB and format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting

I am trying to format a date. I get the date from the database in the dateTime format and i want to show only the date part not the time.

```
 string date = dt.Rows[0]["declaration_date"].ToString();
 string dateFormat = date.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

This is not working. Any help?

Comment: `DateTime date = (DateTime) dt.Rows[0]["declaration_date"];`

Comment: If `declaration_date` is a `DateTime` column you should not convert it to a string. `DateTime result = dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("declaration_date");`

Comment: Your date is already a string, you used 'ToString()' on it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `date.ToString` with formatting to work, date needs to be a DateTime. Try changing your code to something like this:

```
 DateTime date = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["declaration_date"];
 string dateFormat = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Also, your formatting string should be `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it almost correctly.

Try this:

```
string date = dt.Rows[0]["declaration_date"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

The point is that you have to apply `.ToString("MM/dd/yy")` to a `DateTime` object, not to a string.